# How to open URL after clicking at a particular item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am passing a List of objects to my adapter. The objects are of type `Uploads` class which contains just `Docname` and `Docurl`. After displaying the Docname on each of RecyclerView items, I want that when a user clicks at any item, browser should open with the URL corresponding to that item's URL.

This is what I tried. Its not throwing any error and the app is running smoothly but when I click on any item, nothing happens.

```
public class EbookRepresentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EbookRepresentAdapter.EbookRepresentViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Uploads> mbooks;
    public String bookurl;


    public EbookRepresentAdapter(Context context, List<Uploads> books) {
        mContext = context;
        mbooks = books;
    }

    public class EbookRepresentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public Context usecontext;
        public TextView mbookname;


        public EbookRepresentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mbookname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
            usecontext=itemView.getContext();

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(bookurl));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EbookRepresentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.subjectcard,parent,false);
        return new EbookRepresentViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EbookRepresentViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Uploads yearSubjectcurrent= mbooks.get(position);
        String subname=yearSubjectcurrent.getDocname();
        bookurl= yearSubjectcurrent.getDocurl();
        //Log.d(TAG,"subname = "+ subname);
        holder.mbookname.setText(subname);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mbooks.size();
    }
}
```

It would be great if anybody could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`

```
public EbookRepresentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mbookname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
            usecontext=itemView.getContext();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
```

Plus Change this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EbookRepresentViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Uploads yearSubjectcurrent= mbooks.get(position);
        String subname=yearSubjectcurrent.getDocname();
        bookurl= yearSubjectcurrent.getDocurl();
        //Log.d(TAG,"subname = "+ subname);
        holder.mbookname.setText(subname);
```

to

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EbookRepresentViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Uploads yearSubjectcurrent= mbooks.get(position);
    String subname=yearSubjectcurrent.getDocname();
    //bookurl= yearSubjectcurrent.getDocurl(); //delete this line
    //Log.d(TAG,"subname = "+ subname);
    holder.mbookname.setText(subname);

}

    }
```

You are override the bookurl variable.

And Use

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = getLayoutPosition();
            Uploads yearSubjectcurrent= mbooks.get(i);
            bookurl= yearSubjectcurrent.getDocurl();
            //than Intent Code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`

Just use this,

```
        public EbookRepresentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mbookname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
            usecontext=itemView.getContext();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set onClickListener on your itemview
as

```
 public EbookRepresentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mbookname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
            usecontext=itemView.getContext();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
```